# Passing a Subprocedure as parameter to another subprocedure in VB.Net 2008

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, parameters, delegates

I have a bit of a problem. I am currently makeing a webpage that has a few dropdown lists on each page. The purpose of the dropdown lists are to filter the information in a YUI datatable, aswell as eachother's information, eg. a different location will have different commodities etc.

I have made a common function to read the option ID's and values from the DB, but the information can be used in 3 ways. Currently, when the page loads I create a Asp:Placeholder that I load the Dropdown lists in. If the information is requested by Ajax to update a select box, I concatenate a HTML string server side and response.write it. But now my client has requested to have a lookup for if the list in the dropdown box is too long, which I am doing using a YUI modal panel and a YUI grid. I would still like to use the same data fetching subprocedure, but this time I would like to send the data back as a JSON string.

Currently I have boolean flags to signal whether its the pages initial load to create a placeholder, or an update load to make an HTML string, but I would rather like to pass the "information rendering/formatting" subprocedure as a parameter, this eleminating the need for several boolean flags.

My Code

```
    Public Shared Sub LoadCoop(ByRef PlaceHolder As Object, ByVal SearchCriteria As String, ByVal Database As String, ByVal InitialLoad As Boolean)
        Dim SqlConnection As New SqlConnection
        Dim SqlCommand As New SqlCommand
        Dim SqlParameter As New List(Of SqlParameter)
        Dim SqlReader As SqlDataReader = Nothing
        Dim FilterList As New List(Of FilterObject)
        Try
            SqlConnection = CreateDatabaseConnection(ConnectionString)
            AddSqlParameterToCollection(SqlParameter, "@SearchCriteria", SearchCriteria)
            AddSqlParameterToCollection(SqlParameter, "@Database", Database)
            SqlCommand = CreateSqlCommand("[proc_Dynamic_GetCoop]", SqlConnection, SqlParameter)
            SqlReader = SqlCommand.ExecuteReader
            If SqlReader.HasRows Then
                Do While SqlReader.Read
                    Dim TempFilterObject As FilterObject = New FilterObject
                    TempFilterObject.ID = SqlReader("PSCM_COOP_ID")
                    TempFilterObject.Description = SqlReader("PSCM_COOP_ID")
                    FilterList.Add(TempFilterObject)
                Loop
            End If
        If InitialLoad = True Then
            CreateHTMLSelectContainer(PlaceHolder, FilterList, "Coop")
        Else
            CreateHTMLSelectString(FilterList, "Coop")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("ERROR - An error occurred loading the co-op filter. Please contact the system administrators for assistance.")
    Finally
        If Not IsNothing(SqlReader) Then
            SqlReader.Close()
            SqlReader = Nothing
        End If
        If Not IsNothing(SqlCommand) Then
            SqlCommand.Dispose()
            SqlCommand = Nothing
        End If
        If Not IsNothing(SqlConnection) Then
            SqlConnection.Close()
            SqlConnection.Dispose()
            SqlConnection = Nothing
        End If
   End Try
End Sub

Public Shared Sub CreateHTMLSelectContainer(ByRef PlaceHolder As Object, ByVal FilterList As List(Of FilterObject), ByVal ID As String)
            Dim ReturnString As String = ""
            For Each Obj As FilterObject In FilterList
                ReturnString += "opening option tag" & Obj.Description & "closing option tag"
            Next

            Dim Container As New HtmlGenericControl("select")
            Container.ID = "ddl" & ID
            Container.Attributes.Add("class", "filtering_fields_select")
            Container.InnerHtml = ReturnString
            PlaceHolder.Controls.Add(Container)
            If FilterList.Count > 20 Then
                PlaceHolder.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("lookup image goes here"))
            End If
        End Sub

        Public Shared Sub CreateHTMLSelectString(ByVal FilterList As List(Of FilterObject), ByVal ID As String)
            Dim ReturnString As String = "opening select tag"
            Dim Obj As FilterObject = Nothing
            For Each Obj In FilterList
                ReturnString += "opening option tag" & Obj.Description & "closing option tag"
            Next
            ReturnString += "closing select tag"
            If FilterList.Count > 20 Then
                ReturnString += "lookup image goes here"
            End If
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(ReturnString)
        End Sub
```

Comment: Do you really need this `ByRef PlaceHolder As Object` to be passed by reference? It's an object so it's already passed by reference and you aren't doing any `=` reassignments so it can probably be `ByVal` (or just omit it since that's the default). Then you won't need to declare a new delegate, you can just use the appropriate `Action`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The delegate keyword lets you declare a variable type representing a function.  This can then be used in a parameter declaration.  The function is called by using variable_name.Invoke(parameters...).

So something like this:

```
' declares data type representing one of the possible functions
Public Delegate Sub CreateHTMLFunction(ByRef PlaceHolder As Object, ByVal FilterList As List(Of FilterObject), ByVal ID As String)

Public Shared Sub LoadCoop(ByRef PlaceHolder As Object, ByVal SearchCriteria As String, ByVal Database As String, ByVal HTMLFunction As CreateHTMLFunction)
    ' last param is function to call 
    ' snip
    HTMLFunction.Invoke(PlaceHolder, FilterList, "Coop")
End Sub

Public Sub CreateHTMLSelectContainer(ByRef PlaceHolder As Object, ByVal FilterList As List(Of FilterObject), ByVal ID As String)
    ' blah blah
End Sub

Public Sub CreateHTMLSelectString(ByRef PlaceHolder As Object, ByVal FilterList As List(Of FilterObject), ByVal ID As String)
    ' blah blah
End Sub
```

When passing the parameter from the calling code, use AddressOf function_name:

```
        LoadCoop(..., ..., ..., Addressof CreateHTMLSelectContainer)
```

But note all the functions to be passed in will need to have exactly the same parameters list - they must exactly match the definition of the delegate. So you would need to add the PlaceHolder parameter to the SelectString function even if it is not used.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you for the answer.
Its a pity that the parametes have to be the same, unlike javascript that actually just use the parameters it needs.

Comment: Well you can use paramarray to allow an indeterminate list of parameters, by declaring the last parameter something like: 
ByVal ParamArray args() As Object
but that's v. ugly, and I'm sceptical whether it will work with a delegate.  If you've got a load of functions with very different parameter lists it might be worth trying.